# What is the name of this interface element? Indicates position of slide / page

Tags: jquery, .net, html, ios, user-interface

I'm building a user interface and I'm using 'dots' to indicate how many elements there are. They can be used for navigation, but that is optional. I would like to describe this element, but I don't know how this type of element is called. 'Dots or bullets' sound weird and it is more than 'navigation' only.

I've included some examples of this type of user interface element (in other applications). This is a carousel:
[image: The dots in this carousel]

This is a magazine app on an iPad:

[image: The dots in this iPad app]

Another app (mobile website?)

[image]

**How is this element called?** I'm looking for the right name for the Technical Design Document / other documentation. I'm programming it in JavaScript.

Comment: I'd call it a *pager*. p.s, you might have more luck on http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Matt, can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Look more appropriate to [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/). I believe it to be off-topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it's called a Pagination Indicator. Each platform have their own name for it.

Honestly it isn't even a real pattern, just a common imagery used in many patterns to represent a small number of pages.

You'd be best to focus on the data you intend to display. Is it pages for a book, slides of a presentation, tabs of actions etc. Then figure out how to display that and integrate a pagination Indicator in some way.

Think about the max information that needs to be displayed:

- Do you need to show more than 10? - this pager would be unsuitable
- Does the user need to now which page he is on? - swap the current page icon with a number?
- Does the user need to be able to press the icon to go to a page? - then buttons with numbers would be better.

There are many different ways to show pagination: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/16/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/

Comment: Got some documentation or references to help us out?

Comment: I would if you tell me what platform you intend to use this pattern on. Android Pattern -  http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/horizontal-scrolling-page-indicators

Comment: I'm designing for an html5/js. But I have users from multiple platforms - Android, iPhone, PC, Mac, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, it's a [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here is a [tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html) for iOS.

More specifically, I would say the "dots" are simply "current page" indicators.

Answer (score 1):

A *pager* would be one thing to call it. One example of where I've seen it called this is in the [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html).